# how to trigger jquery function on scroll when it shows 100px fro the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have "fun facts" counter on my web site and also a jQuery function which animate counting 
numbers inside fun facts div. Now it is triggered as page loads. I would like to start it when user scrolls down to it. For example when div appears 100px from the bottom of the screen.

This is my jQuery function which starts counting as page loads:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    function count($this){
    var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
    current = current + 10; /* Where 50 is increment */ 
    $this.html(++current);
        if(current > $this.data('count')){
            $this.html($this.data('count'));
        } else {    
            setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
        }
    }           
    $(".stat-count").each(function() {
      $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
      $(this).html('0');
      count($(this));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and here is my try to make it work when user scrolls down to it:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    function count($this){
    var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
    current = current + 10; /* Where 50 is increment */ 
    $this.html(++current);
        if(current > $this.data('count')){
            $this.html($this.data('count'));
        } else {    
            setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 50);
        }
    }        




$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".stat-count").each(function() {


    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {

          $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
          $(this).html('0');
          count($(this));

        }

       }
    }

 })(jQuery);
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
  if(document.body.offsetHeight - event.pageY <= 100 ) {
   //onscoll effect
}

}
```